# PHP preg_match problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

preg_match seems to be implemented in an extremely inconvenient way.  If I use groups and not all of the groups produce a match on a particular string, then rather than returning an array of matches, including empty entries (null or '') the array count is reduced.  This seems at odds with the PHP documentation stating it returns an empty string (or nulls with a flag).  A match array element is only guaranteed (empty or otherwise) if a question mark follows the group, but this is not always desired.

Consider:

```
'/^((\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2})(\.(\d{1,2}))?$/'
```

The unconditional nested groups do not contribute to the matches array at all, not even nulls or ''  If I make the nested group conditional this would undesirably alter the semantics.

When simplified to avoid this (I could then post-process the group values nipping off the unwanted chars):

```
'/^(\d{1,2}:)?(\d{1,2})(\.\d{1,2})?$/'
```

there is still a problem as for some reason the last conditional group fails to generate an empty entry in the matches array.

I am trying to validate and format a duration for an exercise in hrs:mins.secs
This matches:
x (x minutes)
x:y (x hours and y minutes
x:y.z (x hours, y minutes and z seconds)
x.y (x minutes and y seconds)
and other formats fail, which is good.

It is just that there does not seem a convenient way to grab each group match and use it to produce a standard formatted duration string.

Comment: What is the problem? You can grab the groups you need, can't you? What is wrong with `$matches[1]`, ``$matches[2]``, etc.

Comment: You need to read the question more carefully to understand the problem.  Which group does $matches[2] correspond to?  You are unable to determine this if the size of the returned matches array is not constant and does not correspond to the number of groups.  Empty (null or '') are not guaranteed despite the PHP official description.

Comment: You can always check if the group `isset()`. There is no problem with that.

Comment: I could in this particular case but it is inelegant.  I should not need to be checking for this special case.  If PHP was implemented as documented I would not need to.  Of greater concern is the more general issue.  If there is simply no value (as opposed to a null or empty string value) for some groups where a match does not exist then in general we cannot rely upon a particular index/key to be associated with a particular group match.  I think it would be better if we could tag groups and get an array of key=>value pairs where the keys are the tag values.

Answer (score 0):

The missing keys could be optimization. The part of the pattern might not even be executed.

However named groups are possible and you can format the pattern:

```
$pattern = "(
  ^
  (?:(?<hours>\d{1,2}):)?
  (?<minutes>\d{1,2})
  (?:\.(?<seconds>\d{1,2}))?
  $
)Dx";

$data = [
  '42', '21:42', '21:42.1'
];

foreach ($data as $subject) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)) {
        var_dump(
            [
                'hours' => (int)($matches['hours'] ?? 0),
                'minutes' => (int)($matches['minutes'] ?? 0),
                'seconds' => (int)($matches['seconds'] ?? 0)   
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["hours"]=>
  int(0)
  ["minutes"]=>
  int(42)
  ["seconds"]=>
  int(0)
}
array(3) {
  ["hours"]=>
  int(21)
  ["minutes"]=>
  int(42)
  ["seconds"]=>
  int(0)
}
array(3) {
  ["hours"]=>
  int(21)
  ["minutes"]=>
  int(42)
  ["seconds"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Yep, that is what I thought too, optimisation, skipped completely.  I also thought named groups and a matches dictionary would be the best way but I didn't know these had already been implemented in PHP.  That is so useful and resolves my problem completely!